# Jquery dialog not working if there are multiple buttons on the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

there is something weird happening on my webpage.

I want to add a confirmation jquery dialog when I click a button. The problem is....I have that button multiple times on my page, each one having its "id" and is created by php (so there can be 2,3,4,5 buttons on a page).

The button looks like this:

```
            <a href="#" id="confirm" onclick="addlist(<?php echo $v['id'];?>);return false;"><img src="img/item_add.png" alt="add" width="100" height="46" /></a>
```

And this is my jquery

```
  $(document).ready( function(){

$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 600,
    buttons: {
        "Ok": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
    }
});

$('#confirm').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    return false;
    });
});​
```

The problem is that, my jquery code is working just fine, but only for the first button, the second, third...etc not

you have here my example:
http://jsfiddle.net/S4vSU/1/

I want to have that dialog working for every button.
Where is the problem ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use class or **use different id's** like:

```
$('#confirm1, #confirm2').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    return false;
    });
});
```

OR using class:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S4vSU/10/)

Comment: Thanks ! Working as charm. You was the first one with the class idea, so you're the winner. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 5):

"`id`" of particular element must be unique on whole page....

 if not then only one(first) element will be treated....

solution:
give some class to all buttons and instead of id process by class name

e.g:

```
<a class="temp" href="#" id="confirm" onclick="addlist(<?php echo $v['id'];?>);return false;">
    <img src="img/item_add.png" alt="add" width="100" height="46" />
</a>
```

and other code will be

```
$(document).ready( function(){

$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 600,
    buttons: {
        "Ok": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
    }
});

$('.temp').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks ! Working as charm. Point for you, but to be fair, I will accept as answer the one who posted the solution first :)

Answer (score 1):

this is because all your buttons have same id.Id of an element in html should be unique.

You can keep all having same class as I do [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ankur20us/S4vSU/6/)

Comment: Thanks ! As you said, I could use the class instead the id. Point for you, but to be fair, I will accept as answer the one who posted the solution first :)

Answer (score 1):

`id` should be unique for each item.. but you could try to get away using `on()` although it's not recommended:

http://jsfiddle.net/S4vSU/7/

```
$(document).on('click','#confirm', function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: Working in your example, but not on my page :| Weird. However, changing the id for the class is much easier and better. Thank you anyway ;) Point for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use class instead of ID for the element and in click function too.

```
<a class="confirm" href="javascript:;">Confirm 1</a>
<a class="confirm" href="javascript:;">Confirm 2</a>
...
$('.confirm').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks ! That was the solution :) Point to you !